# How Can I Add A Regression Line to pandas.plot(kind='bar)?

Tags: pandas, plot, regression

I'd like to add a regression line for each flavor below. How can I do that? Do I need to use subplots? Is it possible using pandas.plot or do I need to use the full matplotlib?

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [[1,157.842730083188,202.290991182781,244.849416438322],
        [2,234.516775578511,190.104435611797,202.157088214941],
        [3,198.279130213755,193.075780258345,194.112394276613],
        [4,156.285653517235,198.382900113055,185.380696178104],
        [5,190.653607667334,208.807038546447,202.662790911701],
        [6,192.027054343382,168.768097007287,179.315293388299],
        [7,144.927513854729,166.183469310198,157.338388768229],
        [8,194.096584739985,177.710332802887,188.006211652239],
        [9,131.613923150861,112.503607632448,128.947939049068],
        [10,139.545538050778,129.935716833166,139.334073132085]
]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['DensityDecileRank', 'Flavor1', 'Flavor2', 'Flavor3'])

df.plot(x='DensityDecileRank',
        kind='bar',
        stacked=False)
```

Comment: A regression assumes a continuous distribution of `x`. A bar graph charts a categorical `x` value. These can't be combined.

Comment: what would the x and y of your regression? if you want to regress with DensityDecileRank as x, it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind to use numpy to explicitly calculate the regression values,
the following code snippet based on [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-plots-with-pandas-and-numpy-faf2edbfad4f) can be used as a quick solution:

```
ax = df.plot(x='DensityDecileRank', kind='bar', stacked=False)

rank, flavors = df.columns[0], df.columns[1:]
for flavor in flavors:
    reg_func = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(df[rank], df[flavor], 1))
    ax.plot(reg_func(df[rank]))
plt.show()
```

The code above derives the function `reg_func` for each flavor, which can be used for calculating the regression values based on the rank values.
The regression lines are plotted in the order of the flavor columns to match the colors. Further formatting can be added to `ax.plot`.
[image]